# Receiving Callout Exception when calling a .NET service

Tags: soap-api, integration, soap, wsdl2apex, .net

**Background of the service:**
The service is written in .NET and the service is also IP protected.

**The issue:**
The WSDL contains a `ref="s:schema"` element and a s:any element. I have removed the `s:any` element from the WSDL before using WSDL2APEX.

```
      <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element ref="s:schema" />
          <s:any />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
```

The service returns the schema as the following:

```
 public class GetAppointmentDetailsResponse_GetAppointmentDetailsResult_element {
        public List<DOM.XmlNode> anyElement;
        private String[] anyElement_type_info = new String[]{'anyElement','http://tempuri.org/','List<DOM.XmlNode>','0','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'anyElement'};
    }
```

**What has been done:**
We have tried removing the schema element and the s:any from the WSDL, but we still get the same error. We have also confirmed that the request is received by the external server.

If I process the same response through **SOAP UI**, below is what I receive:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetAppointmentDetailsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <GetAppointmentDetailsResult>
            <xs:schema id="ResponseData" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/ResponseData.xsd" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/ResponseData.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ResponseData.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
               <xs:element name="ResponseData" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                  <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="AppointmentDetail">
                           <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                 <xs:element name="Allowed" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="CanOverride" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="Comments" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                              </xs:sequence>
                           </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                     </xs:choice>
                  </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
            <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
               <ResponseData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ResponseData.xsd">
                  <AppointmentDetail diffgr:id="AppointmentDetail1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                     <Allowed>false</Allowed>
                     <CanOverride>false</CanOverride>
                     <Comments>12 NOT FOUND - DUPLICATE</Comments>
                  </AppointmentDetail>
               </ResponseData>
            </diffgr:diffgram>
         </GetAppointmentDetailsResult>
      </GetAppointmentDetailsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The response contains **MSFT** specific elements that we are presumably trying to parse but cannot. The response can be parsed using Data Table inside .NET, but I don't know what is the relative type we can use in Salesforce.com.

.NET code currently in place to call the stub method / parse the response:

```
DataTable test = Service.Method(param1,"" , ClassCommonFunctions.instance.CurrentLocation.LocationName).Tables[0];
```

I have also tried to use other ***WSDL to Apex*** tools like **FUSE IT Explorer**, but still no luck.

**Question:**
Can this response be parsed by Salesforce? If yes, how do I proceed?

Comment: If you cannot get any of the Apex code generating tools to work (including hand editing their outputs) then an approach of last resort is to generate and parse the XML yourself, particularly if the requests and responses that you actually need to use are reasonably simple. Here is [an example](https://force201.wordpress.com/2010/05/20/when-generate-from-wsdl-fails-hand-coding-web-service-calls/).

Comment: @subodhbahl are you able to share the complete WSDL? If you want you could use the Fuse IT SFDC Explorer Wsdl2Apex error reporting to send it through.

Comment: @subodhbahl Are you still interested in solving this? I'd like to help. If you can share a version of the WSDL it will be much easier. Feel free to obscure the actual endpoint URLs.

Comment: @DanielBallingerApologies for not being able to get back. We are working on making the service Salesforce friendly. But, thank you for offering.